# can rank count duplicate value as a specific value in dax?

Tags: duplicates, dax, rank, ssas-tabular

my table in tabular model in like below:

```
Id   Name    Score   
1    mark    20      
2    john    10      
3    jack    20      
4    Jess    20     
5    Brad    9
```

If I use rankx it rank my table as:

```
Id   Name    Score     Rank
1    mark    20        1  
2    john    10        4  
3    jack    20        1
4    Jess    20        1
5    Brad    9         5
```

is there anyway can I have the column rank as below:

```
Id   Name    Score   Rank
1    mark    20      1
2    john    10      4
3    jack    20      2
4    Jess    20      3
5    Brad    9       5
```

Comment: your question is hard to understand - it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three options.

[image]

```
Rank1 = RankX ( 'Table', 'Table'[Score] + ( 0.1/'Table'[ID] ),, DESC )
Rank2 = RankX ( 'Table', 'Table'[Score] ,, DESC, Dense)
Rank3 = RankX ( 'Table', 'Table'[Score] ,, DESC, Skip)
```

In [Rank1] the [ID] value is used to break the ties.
In [Rank2] and [Rank3] the ties are not broken. The `Skip` or `Dense` parameters determine if rankvalues are skipped after a tie or not.